# How to add wcf functionality to an existing asp.net website project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, rest

I have several asp.net website projects for various sites.
Currently I want to add REST API's to these projects so I can start developing mobile apps (using HTML5/JavaScript/CSS3 and PhoneGap) that make use of these webservices.

Since WCF is far more powerful than regular asp.net webservices (among others with control over the service and authentication/authorization), I'd love to add these to my existing website project.

I did a Google search but cant find anywhere a step-by-step tutorial how this can be done. And also if there's any functionality I'd possibly loose when adding WCF functionality
I was also thinking of creating a new project specifically for WCF, but  think I'd rather add it to an existing website project.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Don't add the WCF services to the same project. Create a separate project. Use File->New Project instead of File->New Web Site.

Comment: Why not add it to the same project? As an advantage of adding WCF functionality to the current project I saw the ability to reuse functions (not webservices) that I already wrote in my current project. But you're saying to start a new project? What are the pros and cons? (pretty important before I start messing things up ;) Thanks!

Comment: It's a different kind of project, and besides, web site "projects" are difficult to use with anything much beyond simple content. I strongly recommend against using them with services of any kind, and less strongly recommend against using them at all (but you're already using them, so I don't suggest you stop). Just don't make it worse by adding a WCF service.

Comment: ok. thats clear ;). So I tried File->New project. But which projecttype would you recommend: the ServiceLibrary, Service Application or Syndication Service Library? 

Since I'm creating a different project altogether, I'm thinking of placing that in a virtual directory in my existing website, or is it also possible to compile it to a dll which I then place in the \bin folder (or perhaps add a \webservice folder) of my existing website?
What is the best practice?

Comment: For your first time, just use "WCF Service Application". Do not place it within your site at all. You will deploy to your site when ready, but the project itself won't live within your site - only the finished product will. When complete, publish it to a virtual directory, configured as an application, possibly under your site (you may need to do that to stay within the domain).

Comment: I started a WCF Service application,create a new site in IIS:www.fservice.nl to folder: C:\inetpub\fitness-\fitness-service\WcfFitnessService,but when I call www.fservice.nl/Service1.svc I get: The type 'WcfFitnessService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found. I did a Google search,but cant fnid whats going on for my situation.I must be doing something wrong,cause I dont believe the default settings would throw an error :)

Comment: Sorry, here I am again. Since I'm creating a totally different project. What would be the best way to reuse the code I already wrote in my existing project (such as tableadapters I have in my app_code folder)?

Comment: Please ask a separate question. We do one question per question here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670294/reuse-code-from-website-project-in-my-web-application-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on exactly what your needs are and how your current web site is configured, there are two approaches.

If you are using a Web **Site** Project, then you should create your WCF service in a different application:

1) Create a new ASP.Net Web Application Project.

2) Add a new item to the project and select the type of WCF Service or WCF Data Service.

When you deploy this project, you will deploy it to your web server, but not as part of your web site since configuring the web.config will be a large manual effort.

If you are using a Web **Application** Project, then you could add the WCF Service directly to your existing project. However, I only recommend this approach if you are Silverlight applets within the web site that rely on the user's authenticated credentials.

Answer (score 1):

WCF can be configured with a lot of bindings and it can be configured to return xml or json(.net 4.0). Try to create a wcf service configured to use basichttpbinding or wsHttpBinding and to format the response as json and use jquery to interact with the wcf service. This article might help you http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Cross_Domain_Call.aspx