# Reuse code from website project in my web application project

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

Here's the code. I now also get errors in codebehind that a variable already exists and method has identical signature, but I cant find those duplicates anywhere in the code behind.

**.ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Title="Mijn oefeningen" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/main.master" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Fitness2.exercises" Codebehind="exercises.aspx.vb" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/main.master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHBigBanner" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHQuickSearch" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHCenter" Runat="Server">


<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" />

<div class="section">
<div class="action">
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddNew" runat="server" Text="Nieuwe oefening aanmaken" />    
</div>
</div>


<div class="section">

<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="id" Width="100%" ID="gvExercises" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" CellPadding="10" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="Bottom" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridpager" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="gv_even" Height="20" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gv_odd" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_header" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Bekijk"/>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:linkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ID="Edit" Text="Bewerk" CommandName="EditItem" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        
         <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="title" HeaderText="Oefening naam">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="category" HeaderText="Categorie">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="category" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/delete.png" CausesValidation="false" ID="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit item wilt verwijderen?');" ToolTip="Verwijder" CommandName="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsExercises" runat="server" SortParameterName="sortExpression" SelectMethod="GetExercisesPagedSorted" InsertMethod="InsertExercise" DeleteMethod="DeleteExerciseById" SelectCountMethod="GetExercisesCount" TypeName="ExerciseBLL" EnablePaging="true">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView GridLines="None" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="odsdvExercises" ID="dvExercises" Width="100%" runat="server">
        <Fields>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ControlStyle-CssClass="link" EditText="Item bewerken" NewText="Nieuw item aanmaken" UpdateText="Opslaan" InsertText="Opslaan" ShowEditButton="True" CancelText="Annuleren" ShowInsertButton="true" />               

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("id")%>
                </ItemTemplate>    
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("id")%>
                </EditItemTemplate>    
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>   



            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Oefening naam *" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="title" Width="400" MaxLength="150" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqdfguiredF43ieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ControlToValidate="title" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="title" Width="400" MaxLength="150" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Requdf1giredF43ieldVagfglidator1" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ControlToValidate="title" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doelstelling">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="Lafgdfdbel1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("goal").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="goal" MaxLength="150" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("goal") %>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="goal" MaxLength="150" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tempo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="Lafdgdfdbel1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tempo").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tempo" MaxLength="50" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tempo") %>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tempo" MaxLength="50" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="Lafdgdfdbel1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="description" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="description" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Columns="50" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aantal sets">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="La1fgdfdbel1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sets").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="sets" MaxLength="2" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sets") %>'/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="sets" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="sets" MaxLength="2" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="sets" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Minimum herhalingen">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="La1f3gdfdbel1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reprange_min").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="reprange_min" MaxLength="2" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reprange_min") %>'/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="reprange_min" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExpresfsionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="reprange_min" MaxLength="2" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="reprange_min" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExpresfsionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Maxmimum herhalingen">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="La1f3gdfdb6el1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reprange_max").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="reprange_max" MaxLength="2" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reprange_max") %>'/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="reprange_max" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExspressionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="reprange_max" MaxLength="2" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="reprange_max" ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularsExpressionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Minuten">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="La11f3gdfdb6el1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("minutes").tostring %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="minutes" MaxLength="3" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("minutes") %>'/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="minutes"  ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="minutes" MaxLength="3" Width="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="minutes"  ValidationGroup="Exercises" ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig getal" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YouTube link">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="La11f3gdfd2b6el1c" runat="server" Text='<%# Fitness2.GlobalFunctions.GetVideoEmbed(Eval("youtube").tostring) %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="youtube" MaxLength="50" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("youtube") %>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="youtube" MaxLength="2" Width="400" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Text=""/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Categorie" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1b" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("category") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Selecteer bestaande categorie:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("category") %>' DataSourceID="sqldsCategories" DataTextField="title" DataValueField="title" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>of maak een nieuwe categorie aan:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="category" Width="200" MaxLength="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequirebbdF43ieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="tasks" ControlToValidate="category" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Selecteer bestaande categorie:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" DataSourceID="sqldsCategories" DataTextField="title" DataValueField="title" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>of maak een nieuwe categorie aan:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="category" Width="200" MaxLength="50" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequirebbdF43ieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="tasks" ControlToValidate="category" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



        </Fields>


      </asp:DetailsView>


<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsdvExercises" TypeName="ExerciseBLL" SelectMethod="GetExerciseById" InsertMethod="InsertExercise" UpdateMethod="UpdateExercise" runat="server">
        <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvExercises" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>  
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsCategories" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:conn1 %>" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>



</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHRight" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

**.ASPX.VB**

```
Imports Fitness2.GlobalFunctions
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Partial Class exercises
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private _userid As String
```

**here I get error: '_userid' is already declared as 'Private _userid As String' in this class.**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

**Here I get error: 'Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.**

```
_userid = GetFieldFromSession(Session, "//root/user/userid")

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        BindExercises()
    End If


End Sub



'**************** TASKS ****************
Protected Sub BindExercises()
    odsExercises.SelectParameters.Clear()
    gvExercises.DataSourceID = "odsExercises"
    odsExercises.SelectParameters.Add("maximumRows", gvExercises.PageSize)
    odsExercises.SelectParameters.Add("startRowIndex", gvExercises.PageIndex)
    odsExercises.SelectParameters.Add("sortExpression", odsExercises.SortParameterName)
    odsExercises.SelectParameters.Add("userid", _userid)
    'gvExercises.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub lbtnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Title As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("title"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim userid As String = _userid
    Dim goal As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("goal"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim tempo As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("tempo"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim description As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("description"), TextBox).Text)
    If description.Length > 4000 Then description = description.Substring(0, 4000)

    Dim sets As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("sets"), TextBox).Text), sets)
    Dim reprange_min As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("reprange_min"), TextBox).Text), reprange_min)
    Dim reprange_max As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("reprange_max"), TextBox).Text), reprange_max)
    Dim minutes As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("minutes"), TextBox).Text), minutes)

    Dim youtube As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("youtube"), TextBox).Text)
    'Dim ispublic As Boolean = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ispublic"), CheckBox).Checked

    Dim category As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("category"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim categorydropdown As DropDownList = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ddlcategory"), DropDownList)
    If category = "" Then 'user wants to create new category
        If categorydropdown.Items.Count = 0 Then
            lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Maak aub eerst een categorie aan", True)
        Else
            If categorydropdown.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then category = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ddlcategory"), DropDownList).Text
        End If
    End If


    Dim TA As New fitnessTableAdapters.exercisesTableAdapter
    Dim returnval As Integer
    TA.InsertExercise(New Guid(userid), Title, category, goal, tempo, description, sets, reprange_min, reprange_max, minutes, youtube, "", False, 0, returnval)
    If returnval > 0 Then
        Session("exerciseId") = returnval
        gvExercises.DataBind()
        lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Oefening toegevoegd", False)
    Else
        lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Whoops", True)
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub dvExercises_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles dvExercises.ItemInserting
    Dim Title As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("title"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim userid As String = _userid
    Dim goal As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("goal"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim tempo As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("tempo"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim description As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("description"), TextBox).Text)
    If description.Length > 4000 Then description = description.Substring(0, 4000)

    Dim sets As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("sets"), TextBox).Text), sets)
    Dim reprange_min As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("reprange_min"), TextBox).Text), reprange_min)
    Dim reprange_max As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("reprange_max"), TextBox).Text), reprange_max)
    Dim minutes As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("minutes"), TextBox).Text), minutes)

    Dim youtube As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("youtube"), TextBox).Text)
    'Dim ispublic As Boolean = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ispublic"), CheckBox).Checked

    Dim category As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("category"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim categorydropdown As DropDownList = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ddlcategory"), DropDownList)
    If category = "" Then 'user wants to create new category
        If categorydropdown.Items.Count = 0 Then
            lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Maak aub eerst een categorie aan", True)
        Else
            If categorydropdown.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then category = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ddlcategory"), DropDownList).Text
        End If
    End If

    Dim TA As New fitnessTableAdapters.exercisesTableAdapter
    Dim returnval As Integer
    TA.InsertExercise(New Guid(userid), Title, category, goal, tempo, description, sets, reprange_min, reprange_max, minutes, youtube, "", False, 0, returnval)
    If returnval > 0 Then
        Session("exerciseId") = returnval
        gvExercises.DataBind()
        lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Oefening toegevoegd", False)
    Else
        lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Whoops", True)
    End If

    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Protected Sub odsdvExercises_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles odsdvExercises.Inserted
    gvExercises.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub odsdvExercises_Updated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles odsdvExercises.Updated
    gvExercises.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub dvExercises_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles dvExercises.ItemUpdating

    Dim ID As Integer = CInt(dvExercises.DataKey.Value)
    'retrieve controls
    Dim Title As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("title"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim userid As String = _userid
    Dim goal As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("goal"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim tempo As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("tempo"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim description As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("description"), TextBox).Text)
    If description.Length > 4000 Then description = description.Substring(0, 4000)

    Dim sets As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("sets"), TextBox).Text), sets)
    Dim reprange_min As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("reprange_min"), TextBox).Text), reprange_min)
    Dim reprange_max As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("reprange_max"), TextBox).Text), reprange_max)
    Dim minutes As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("minutes"), TextBox).Text), minutes)

    Dim youtube As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("youtube"), TextBox).Text)
    'Dim ispublic As Boolean = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ispublic"), CheckBox).Checked

    Dim category As String = Trim(CType(dvExercises.FindControl("category"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim categorydropdown As Integer = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ddlcategory"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
    If categorydropdown <> -1 Then category = CType(dvExercises.FindControl("ddlcategory"), DropDownList).Text

    Dim TA As New fitnessTableAdapters.exercisesTableAdapter
    Dim dt As fitness.exercisesDataTable = TA.GetExerciseById(ID)
    Dim returnval As Integer = TA.Update(New Guid(userid), Title, category, goal, tempo, description, sets, reprange_min, reprange_max, minutes, youtube, dt(0).locpath.ToString, False, DateTime.Now, ID)

    Select Case returnval
        Case 0
            lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Whoops", True)
        Case 1
            gvExercises.DataBind()
            lblStatus.Text = GetStatus("Item opgeslagen", False)
    End Select
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Protected Sub gvExercises_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvExercises.RowDataBound
    Dim gvr As GridViewRow = e.Row
    If gvr.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim imgBtn As ImageButton
        imgBtn = CType(e.Row.FindControl("Delete"), ImageButton)
        imgBtn.CommandArgument = gvr.RowIndex.ToString

        Dim lnkBtn As LinkButton
        lnkBtn = CType(e.Row.FindControl("Edit"), LinkButton)
        lnkBtn.CommandArgument = gvr.RowIndex.ToString
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub gvExercises_OnRowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvExercises.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "DeleteEvent" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim data As DataKey = gvExercises.DataKeys(index)
        Dim objectId As Integer = data.Values("id")
        odsExercises.DeleteParameters.Clear()
        odsExercises.DeleteParameters.Add("id", objectId)
        odsExercises.Delete()
    End If

    If e.CommandName = "EditItem" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim data As DataKey = gvExercises.DataKeys(index)
        Dim objectId As Integer = data.Values("id")
        'floran
        ViewState("id") = objectId.ToString
        BindDetailsView()
        'gvExercises.SelectedValue
        'dvExercises.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub dvExercises_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dvExercises.ItemCommand

End Sub

Protected Sub BindDetailsView()
    Dim TA As New fitnessTableAdapters.exercisesTableAdapter
    dvExercises.DataSourceID = ""
    dvExercises.DataSource = TA.GetExerciseById(ViewState("id")) ' customer.FetchByCustomerType(ViewState("CustomerType").ToString())
    dvExercises.DataBind()
    dvExercises.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit)

End Sub

Protected Sub btnAddNew_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
    dvExercises.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert)
End Sub

Protected Sub gvExercises_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gvExercises.SelectedIndexChanged
    If gvExercises.SelectedDataKey IsNot Nothing Then
        Session("exerciseId") = CInt(gvExercises.SelectedDataKey.Value)
        'ReportError("Session(exerciseId)", Session("exerciseId").ToString)
    End If
End Sub




End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than keeping both solutions, I'd convert the website project to a WAP.

You'll need to move everything in your app_code folder in the website project either into a separate class library or just include them in the WAP directly (probably without the app_code folder, as that has special significance), in which case they'll be compiled into the primary WAP assembly.

You may have to play with namespaces, etc. in order to get this to work correctly, but the impact should be minimal. The major difference (and benefit) is that the code is built at compile time, and your source (*.cs) is not deployed to the server.

Also note that, in VS, there's a context menu option to convert website project entities into web application entities. This will create the .designer.cs files needed by the WAP as well as organize the files in the solution explorer - the .aspx, .cs and .designer.cs files will appear as an expandable node.

[Here's an excellent article on MSDN covering the conversion process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Once you've got the WAP running, adding services is as simple as `right click - add new item...`

Comment: Interesting...im working on that now, but run into an issue:
I have this:
<%@ Master Language="VB" Inherits="Fitness2.main" Codebehind="main.master.vb" %>
But I get "Could not load type 'Fitness2.main'", I then change it to Inherits="main" and get "Could not load type 'Fitness2.main'"

In my main.master.vb I have: 
Partial Class main
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
What should this line say?
<%@ Master Language="VB" Inherits="Fitness2.main" Codebehind="main.master.vb" %>

Comment: `Could not load type` means that the system could not find a class in any of the DLLs in the `bin` folder with that name - either because there was an error while compiling (assuming you DID compile the site) or because you've got the class or namespace name wrong. Make sure that, in your WAP project, the build action for `main.master.vb` is set to Compile, and that you've actually built the solution before viewing it in a browser.

Comment: I guess thats different from the website project?I now get an error: 
    '''<remarks>
    '''Auto-generated field
    '''</remarks>
    Protected WithEvents btnAddNew As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button   <--'btnAddNew' is already declared as 'Protected WithEvents btnAddNew As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' in this class. 
in "exercises.aspx.designer.vb"
Is that because I already have this in "exercises.aspx": 
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNew" runat="server" Text="New" /> 
What should I delete and what exactly is the function of the 'withevents' signatures in "exercises.aspx.designer.vb"?

Comment: need to see it. Update your question with the vb and aspx (not the designer) code.

Comment: Ok, I updated tha question. Maxlength was 30.000 so I had to remove some parts that seemed not relevant for my question. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Floran - The source looks fine, which leads me to believe that your .vb file is being included twice, which would cause `duplicate definition` errors for everything. Do you have two copies of the same class within the project? Have you made sure that everything is out of the app_code folder?

Comment: I uploaded my solution here: http://www.wunderwedding.com/files/Fitness2.zip perhaps you see something weird in the project structure?
I cleaned some files that are not relevant for my question.

Comment: @Floran I'll take a look. Bored this morning anyway.

Comment: first of all, best wishes for 2012! Did you find the time to look at this (or have you not been too bored lately ;)?

Comment: @Floran I can't build the solution you posted; I'm looking at the code, but something I can compile to reproduce the error would be useful. You can email me directly (davidlively at g mail)

Comment: @Floran this exchange is getting too long for the comments section, but the one thing that jumps out at me is several *.designer.vb named things like 'various1.designer.vb.' Removing those, or renaming them, gets rid of quite a few errors. Email me.

Comment: Hi David,I know,I will try your suggestion and email you should I have any further questions...thanks for the help so far!